# Where to put google-services.json in Titanium project?

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am working on the push notification for Android app using Titanium.
I have already created the GCM Server API key and Sender ID.
And downloaded the configuration file

> google-services.json

where should I put this file into my Titanium project?

Comment: matbe /app directory

Comment: I didn't see such directory in my project root. Do I need to create it myself?

Comment: if you don't have the /app then you might have /src. May be in titanium /src is same as /app in android studio.

Comment: None of those make sense. "app" is a directory that is used in Alloy and is the root for the MVC-subdirectories. "src" is only used when using Hyperloop and can include native classes and frameworks. So in case it really needs to be in the Titanium application, it should go into "app/platform/android" for Alloy and "platform/android" for classic projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `google-services.json` is a convenience step for native apps for easy GCM/ FCM integration.

For integrating push notifications to Titanium project, you have to first decide how you would like to send your notifications. There are services like [Arrow Push](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Sending_and_Scheduling_Push_Notifications) and [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) that allow you to send notification from a graphical web console.

If you want to go ahead with Arrow Push you may check [Titanium CloudPush Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.CloudPush)

> The CloudPush module supports Android push notifications for a device
>   by providing a connection to the push notification server to the
>   device to receive push notifications and to optionally present a tray
>   notification to the user when a new push notification is received.

In your project's tiapp.xml, you need to add some keys to configure push notifications.

```
<!-- Property keys for Arrow Push (required) -->
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">YOUR DEVELOPMENT API KEY HERE</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">YOUR PRODUCTION API KEY HERE</property>
<property name="acs-api-key" type="string">YOUR API KEY HERE</property>
```

For integrating Firebase Notifications, not sure if we have a good Firebase Titanium android module yet. [Appcelerator / Titanium module project](https://github.com/chrisribe/ti-firebase) exists to build and use the Firebase SDK but it doesn't integrate Firebase notifications as per [this](https://github.com/chrisribe/ti-firebase/issues/3) issue.

There are few [Titanium GCM modules](http://gitt.io/search?q=gcm) also, you'll have to see how you can provide GCM sender id/ key in these modules.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I have a clearer picture.